# How to call a payable function with multiple parameters using web3 in Truffle Console

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

Here's my contract code:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.9;

contract hodl {

  event printNum(uint num);
  event printValue(uint val);

  function deposit(uint number) payable public {
    emit printNum(number);
    emit printValue(msg.value);
  }
    
}
```

Here's what I'm doing in `truffle console`:

```
truffle(ganache)> c = await hodl.deployed()
undefined
truffle(ganache)> c.deposit(420).sendTransaction({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], value: 10000000000000000000})
evalmachine.<anonymous>:0
c.deposit(420).sendTransaction({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], value: 10000000000000000000})
               ^

Uncaught TypeError: c.deposit(...).sendTransaction is not a function
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can call payable contract method along with some ether and sender.

```
c.deposit(420, { value: 10000000000000000000, from: web3.eth.accounts[0]})
```